# Error: time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Estoy intentando analizar los dias entre fechas que tengo en un archivo excel.
Cargo el archivo con pandas y defino la función

```
import datetime

def days_between(d1, d2):
    return abs(d2 - d1).days
```

Luego el codigo es el siguiente

```
grouped = df_.groupby('id')
c = 12
for x in grouped:
    print(type(x[1]['DATE'].values[0]))
    d1_str = str(x[1]['DATE'].values[0])
    d2_str = str(x[1]['DATE'].values[len(x[1]['DATE'])-1])
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    d = days_between(d2, d1)
```

luego me tira el error

```
ValueError: time data '2019-03-22T11:09:27.000000000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

En el error veo que me lee uno de los datos como 2019-03-22T11:09:27.0000 con una "T" entremedio, no se a que se debe.

Los datos son del tipo

[image: Los datos son del tipo]

Comment: Saludos maestro @FJSevilla estoy iniciando en python por pura curiosidad, acabo de responder a la pregunta, me gustaría saber su opinión sobre la respuesta :)

Comment: ¡Hola fredyfx!, bienvenido a Python pero ten cuidado con la curiosidad como dijo D.Parker "El aburrimiento se cura con curiosidad. La curiosidad no se cura con nada" :) Tu respuesta es una forma simple de resolver el problema con el formato que plantea la pregunta, aunque el OP me temo que se está complicando mucho en mi opinión. `dateutil` junto a `pytz` (zonas horarias) son dos librerías muy buenas que complementan a `datetime` de la stdlib.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias maestro @FJSevilla ! esa frase ya se me quedó en el alma :D Estaré tratando de responder conforme pueda, de usted aprenderé a lo grande, ¡gracias nuevamente por siempre compartir la sabiduría! Que tenga un buen día :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estás buscando una solución para un problema que te has creado innecesariamente. Tu columna `DATE` es de tipo `pandas.datetime64`, no hay absolutamente ninguna necesidad de pasarla a `datetime.datetime` de Python estándar para operar. Con ello te complicas la vida y está haciendo una operación muy ineficiente dado que primero obtienes la representación en forma de cadena de la fecha, luego construyes el objeto `datetime.datetime` y terminas llamando a una función.

Para poder hacer reproducible el ejemplo, voy a partir de un xlsx con la siguiente estructura:

> ```
> id    DATE
> 1     13/10/2019 12:24:27
> 2     14/10/2019 15:30:12
> 2     15/10/2019 14:24:17
> 1     16/10/2019 01:40:14
> 3     17/10/2019 12:03:27
> 4     18/10/2019 03:18:37
> 1     19/10/2019 12:04:55
> 2     20/10/2019 17:54:07
> 3     21/10/2019 14:14:17
> 4     22/10/2019 06:20:08
> 3     23/10/2019 02:57:03
> 3     24/10/2019 22:23:14
> 2     25/10/2019 19:47:27
> 4     26/10/2019 09:13:35
> ```

Primero de todo, para convertir de `numpy.datetime64` a `datetime.datetime` no tienes que convertir a cadena y usar `strptime`, es mucho más simple y eficiente usar el método `astype`:

> ```
> >>> import datetime
> >>> import numpy as np
>
> >>> np_dt64 = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now())
> >>> np_dt64 
> numpy.datetime64('2019-08-22T05:19:51.408199')
> >>> str(np_dt64)
> '2019-08-22T05:19:51.408199'
> >>> dt = np_dt64.astype(datetime.datetime)
> >>> dt
> datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 22, 5, 19, 51, 408199)
> ```

por lo tanto, basta con que hacer en tu caso:

```
d1 = x[1]['DATE'].values[0]).astype(datetime.datetime)
d2 = x[1]['DATE'].values[-1]).astype(datetime.datetime)
```

> **Nota:** recuerda que Python/NumPy permiten usar índices negativos, si quieres el último elemento de un array basta con hacer `array[-1]`, no necesitas hacer `array[len(array)-1]`

Por otro lado, la conversión a `datetime.datetime` es innecesaria, siguiendo tu idea, puedes obtener la diferencia de días entre la primera y la última fila de cada grupo usando NumPy directamente:

```
import pandas as pd

df_ = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
grouped = df_.groupby('id')
for x in grouped:
    d1, d2 = x[1]['DATE'].values[[0, -1]]
    delta = d2 - d1
    dias = delta.astype('timedelta64[D]').item().days
    print(f"ID: {x[0]} DELTA: {dias} dias")
```

> ```
> ID: 1 DELTA: 5 dias
> ID: 2 DELTA: 11 dias
> ID: 3 DELTA: 7 dias
> ID: 4 DELTA: 8 dias
> ```

No obstante, por lo general cuando usas Pandas debes aprovecha siempre lo que éste y NumPy te ofrecen, evitando recurrir a ciclos y funciones Python crudas si no son estrictamente necesarias. Puedes hacer esto sin uso de ciclos directamente con Pandas, por ejemplo se me ocurre:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df_ = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
deltas = (df_.groupby('id')
             .nth([0, -1])
             .groupby("id")
             .agg("diff")["DATE"]
             .dt
             .days)
deltas = deltas.loc[~deltas.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

> ```
> id
> 1     5
> 2    11
> 3     7
> 4     8
> ```

El resultado es una `Serie` con la `id` como índice y su diferencia de días para su primera y última fecha como valor. Si alguna `id` tiene una sola fecha (una sola fila con esa `id`) aparece con el valor `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import dateutil.parser #Esta es la librería que hace la magia

def days_between(d1, d2):
    return abs(d2 - d1).days

r1 = dateutil.parser.parse('2019-03-22T11:09:27.0000000000')
print(r1)
r2 = dateutil.parser.parse('2019-04-24T11:09:27.0000000000')
print(r2)
r3 = days_between(r2,r1)
print(r3)
```

Y el resultado:

```
2019-03-22 11:09:27 #r1
2019-04-24 11:09:27 #r2
33                  #r3
```